# Is auth.token.email in Firebase callable function safe?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

My Firebase project only uses Google Auth. I want to make some admin only callable functions. To do this, I check if `context.auth.token.email` is in the admin list.

I'm not sure this is safe or not. Is it possible for an attacker to call the function with a fake `context.auth` which has an email address of another Google Account?

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Functions runtime [verifies that ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) that it receives in the `Bearer` header, before it sets it in `context.auth`. So while a malicious user can pass any value they like, it won't be a valid ID token for your project and thus be rejected in this verification.

The token in `context.auth` is passed from the client, is actually minted by the server (or by another piece of code that has access to the administrative credentials of your project).

Answer (score 0):

> I check if context.auth.token.email is in the admin list.

As long as the list can be edited by you (or any authorized person only), it's fine.

> Is it possible for an attacker to call the function with a fake context.auth which has an email address of another Google Account?

No, unless they have access to that Google Account itself and login to your application with it.